# What kind of object is a CalendarEvent?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a script that will pull a day's events from Google Calendars and, eventually, make an emailed agenda. I'm adapting a snippet from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/templates.

```
// Get today's events
var now = new Date();
var morning = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var night = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 23, 59, 59, 999)
var cals = [[in the real code, this contains about 30 valid, properly structured calendar IDs with commas and single quotes in all the right places]];
Logger.log(cals.length); //double-checking number to ensure that I didn't miss a calendar
//cycle through calendars and get events
var events = [];
var working;
var currentCal;
for (var i=0; i<cals.length; i++){
  currentCal = cals[i];
  working = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(currentCal).getEvents(morning,night);
  Logger.log(working.getTitle());
  events.push(working[0]);
}
Logger.log(events);
```

I have tried a variety of tactics in that penultimate Logger.log call. Initially, it was just logging working. The thing is, I cannot get it to stop logging "CalendarEvent"—the string, literally, just as it is here—instead of the actual calendar event. Events logs as an array of nulls and the occasional "CalendarEvent." I suspect I'm overlooking something stupid here, like the type of object "working" actually is.

So, what kind of object should a CalendarEvent be? Is it, as I suspect, its own structured thing, or is it simply an array that contains the title, times, description, etc. of the event? (As you can see above, I tried treating it as an array, but to no avail.)

Comment: Run in console `console.log(cals)` and you will see the structure.

Comment: I just tried that. It output the array of calendar IDs, just as I would expect it to. Events still logs as [null, null, CalendarEvent, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null].

Comment: Actually, that CalendarEvent shouldn't even be there—there are no events on any of the calendars today.

Comment: Guess you are not getting good response. Calendar event should be like this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource

Comment: That looks like it's for the API, though. Is there a difference between the API version of a calendar event and the Google Apps Script version? The good news is that it's now only putting "CalendarEvent" in that array when there actually is one, but thatArray.toString() == '' is still evaluating as true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of throwing just about everything at this particular wall, I seem to have stumbled onto a solution!! Posting here in case anyone else out there runs into this particular issue.

I can't explain why, but the following works:

```
// Get today's events
var now = new Date();
var morning = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var night = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 23, 59, 59, 999)
var cals = [properly formatted array of about 30 different calendar IDs];
Logger.log(cals.length); //double-checking number of employees to ensure that I didn't miss a calendar
//cycle through calendars and get events
var events = [];
var working = [];
var currentCal;
for (var i=0; i<cals.length; i++){
  currentCal = cals[i];
  working = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(currentCal).getEvents(morning,night); 
if (working.length != 0) {
  Logger.log("Working "+ working[0]);
  events.push.apply(events,working);
  Logger.log("First event "+events[0]);
  Logger.log(events[0].getTitle());
}}
```

Explicitly treating working and events as arrays seems to have helped significantly...or that could have had nothing whatsoever to do with it. All I know is, this now pulls an event title from the right event. (I still need to test it with multiple events in multiple calendars, though.) I also changed the code above to include only calendarEvents in the events array, instead of one calendarEvent and 30 nulls.